# Handling non-AscII characters in HTML using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm pulling data off a website that, when looking at the source code uses `<td class="xxx">&nbsp;</td>`, but when pulled using beautiful soup shows up in the python interpreter as `<td class="xxx">Tá</td>`. I'm trying to target the data that is in that td. Right now it is empty. Something like below hasn't worked, because this isn't an Ascii character. Help!!:

```
result = <td class="xxx">&nbsp;</td>

#Check to see if it is returning an empty string
if not result:
    print 'empty'
```

Comment: Neither 'Tá' or '&nbsp;' (Or a string with a literal nbsp) are going to be empty strings. Also, BeautifulSoup isn't going to transform "&nbsp" into "Tá"… could you show us more source? A URL to the HTML?

Comment: Sure. This is the URL [link](http://electionresults.virginia.gov/resultsPREC.aspx?type=SWR&rid=169&cty=550&osn=6) - it's teh data in this TD: '<td class="ig_82354991_26"></td>'

Comment: <strike>Is there supposed to be a URL after the colon in that comment?</strike> there we go. :-)

Comment: There's about a billion `<td>`s in that source: how are you narrowing down the HTML? (How are you computing `result`?) If you can post a minimal test case that exhibits your problem, it'll allow us to run it / debug it.

Comment: yeah, [here it is](http://electionresults.virginia.gov/resultsPREC.aspx?type=SWR&rid=169&cty=550&osn=6)

Answer (score 1):

I've been using the [Unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) package to help me decode unicode that's been getting passed to me by upstream clients. It seems to work in all my current test cases. Basically it takes unicode and attempts to turn it into its ASCII equivalent.